# How to define a method which will return a edited global variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to edit the difficulty of my game with a main menu using tkinter. When a button is pressed, easy, medium or hard; the radius of the targets should change size (harder=smaller). However, when I click the button it does not change the radius and instead leaves the it at the previously defined global variable of 20.

I've tried passing app as an argument through play.

```
radius = 20   

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        self.difficulty = -1

        self.grid()
        self.login = self.create_main()
        self.read = None

    def changeVariable1(self):
        self.difficulty = 12

    def changeVariable2(self):
        self.difficulty = 16

    def changeVariable3(self):
        self.difficulty = 20

    def diff(self):
        global radius
        if self.difficulty == 12:
            radius = (30)
        elif self.difficulty == 16:
            radius = (20)
        elif self.difficulty == 20:
            radius = (10)

    def create_read(self):
        read = Toplevel()
        read.geometry("%dx%d%+d%+d" % (500, 500, 250, 125))

        Label(read, text="Menu ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=4)
        Label(read, text="    ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=1, column=1)
        Label(read, text="Difficulty: ", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=3, column=1)

        Button(read, text="Easy", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable1).grid(row=3, column=2)
        Button(read, text="Medium", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable2).grid(row=3, column=3)
        Button(read, text="Hard", font='Helvetica 10 bold', command=self.changeVariable3).grid(row=3, column=4)

def play():
    rgb = (random(), random(), random())

    timeTaken = time() - startTime

    circles.append(my_circle(rgb))

    screen.title('SCORE: {}, TIME LEFT: {}'.format(score, int(round(gameLength - timeTaken, 0))))

    if time() - startTime > gameLength:
        screen.title('FINAL SCORE: {}'.format(score))
        screen.onclick(None)
        screen.clear()
    else:
        screen.ontimer(play, 1000 // app.difficulty)

root = Tk()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()

score = 0

circles = []

gameLength = 30

screen.onclick(lambda x, y: deletescore())

startTime = time()

play()

screen.mainloop()
```

I expect that when I click the button it changes the radius from 20 to its respective value, easy = 30, med = 20, hard = 10.

Comment: All the button command functions in your code just change the difficulty and the function `diff`, which actually change the radius, is never executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your menu callback calls `self.changeVariableX`, but those only set `self.difficulty`. The method `diff`, which sets the global `radius` based on `self.difficulty`, is never called.

When trying to figure out problems like this, a good idea is to print out some debug information (using `print`) or to use a debugger that allows you to follow step-by-step what happens when you press a menu button.

Comment: Thanks Florian, but where would it be appropriate to call my diff method?

Comment: The best place with your current code would be at the end of the `changeVariableX` methods (after they've set `difficulty`). By the way, feel free to post your code over at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) *once you get it working* to get some tips on making it more Pythonic ;)